# Find word and extract the table from large text file

Tags: python, text-files

I've trying to solve the following issue, but I can't get it to work. My question is the following:

I have a long text file 900+ pages from where I want to extract a certain table. The downside is that the file is not all in the same format. For example I want to extract the table of the "Product sales" (see file). Above and below the table are completely different layouts of the text file. Can someone please help, thanks in advance! I was able to come to this, but not able to create a proper table (i.e. pandas df) from this.

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")      
searchlines = f.readlines()
searchlines = [x.strip() for x in searchlines] 

f.close()
index = []
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "Product Sales" in line:
        index.append(i)

df = searchlines[index[0]:index[1]]
```

http://www.filedropper.com/stackfile

Comment: Post the real file (or a link to if it's huge), not an image. Also, is this this one single file and a one-shot script or do you have many more or less similar files to process on a regular basis ?

Comment: NB basically all you need is a way to identify on which line the useful part starts.

Comment: Please _do not_ post code in comments, it's totally unreadable. Edit your post instead.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your comments. You I do have to proces the same file on a regular basis. I can't find how to upload the file..

Comment: Don't upload the file, post a link to some pastebin or similar site.

Comment: ah oke thanks, new to posting questions. But I think it works now

Comment: Is the picture the file you want to read. What is the output  you want or is that the output format your want . Make it clear

Comment: @Gerard one last point: is your problem extracting the relevant lines from the file or is your current code working for this part and your problem only creating a panda dataframe from it ?

Comment: Hi Bruno. Extracting the relevant lines work with the code i pasted. The problem is transforming that to a table (dataframe) I can actually use to do calculations with, make plots etc.

Answer (score 0):

[awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) is able to help you to identify when you are in a table.

Try `awk '$1=="Product"&&$2=="Sales"{print "table start"}{print NF, $0}' myfile.txt > output.txt` and you'll see that you are able to detect begining of table, then table lines - cells are in $1 .. $10 - then end of table - two empty lines.

You can work on that and come back with question if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know absolutely nothing on awk, so I will try to figure out how it works. I